# GRIDSTER scroll is not moving while darging and resize to its parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gridster

I need to move the scrollbar of parent div #mainContainer while drag and resize.
Please help me out this issue.

```
<div id="mainContainer" style="overflow:auto;">
    <div class="gridster">
<ul>
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"></li>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
    <li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"></li>
</ul>
```

```
$(function(){ //DOM Ready

$(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
});
```

});

Check this image link

http://tinypic.com/r/2rm9ydf/8

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

give height and width as per your requirement

```
<div id="mainContainer" style="overflow:auto;height:300px;width:95%;">
<div class="gridster">
<ul>
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work out. What i need is when i drag or resize, Parent div id="mainContainer" scroll bar needs to move.

Comment: Please check the image link